# How to make WPF User Control elements inherit parent style and then add in custom styles?

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my ResourceDictionary.xaml, I have:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="...">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

In my Main.xaml, I have:

```
<DataGrid ...>
...
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</DataGrid.Resources>
...
</DataGrid>
```

and also:

```
<DataGrid ...>
...
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <local:Results />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
...
</DataGrid>
```

Finally, inside Results.xaml, I have:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
       <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

At this point, I expect all data grid cells in Results.xaml to have both `Background = Red` and `HorizontalAlignment = Right`.

From what I found online, this line means inherit the existing styles of DateGridCell (`BasedOn`) and append new style into it (`Setter`), but the result is only `HorizontalAlignment = Right` is applied

If I remove the `<style>` then the background becomes Red.

At this point, I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: What is the Background of <local:Results />?